# Java CriteriaQuery disjoint result

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, java-ee-6, criteria-api

I have three predicates:

```
Predicate predicate1 = cb.equal(c.get(Transport_.winnerid).get(User_.id), 1L);

Predicate predicate2 = cb.notEqual(c.get(Transport_.senderid).get(User_.id),  user.getID());

Path<Long> longpath = c.join(Transport_.bidList).join(Bid_.bidderid).get(User_.id);

Predicate predicate3 = cb.equal(longpath, user.getID());
```

Now I want a fourth predicate that returns:

```
predicate4=(Predicate1 && predicate2) minus ("disjoint") predicte3
```